# как встроить в панель поиска win10 свое приложение при помощи python

Tags: python, windows-10, search

всем привет.
возникла задача по поиску телефонных номеров через LDAP и при этом выдавать результат в панели win10
например ввел фамилию в панели поиска win10 а мне выдает данные которые есть AD. желательно на python это сделать. это реально?
[image: запрос]

Comment: Вы как то можете подробней расписать свой вопрос, ничего не понял 

Comment: мне ружно что бы результаты поиска брались из AD по LDAP и отображались в панели поиска. т.е. есть список пользователей в AD и что бы не заходить в справочник адресной книги что бы посмотреть телефон или други данные о пользователе я в поиске пишу фамилию и все данные о пользователе выходят в результатах поиска панели, как на скрине.

Comment: А просто написать софт с интерфейсом не хотите? Зачем пытаться костылеть это в интерфейс винды? А так можно скажем апатч поднять, на нем разместить свой сайт и перенаправить все запросы в интернет с поиска на этот сайт... Или как то сам интерфейс ковырять. В любом случае это уже явно не питон;))